# Iframe Animation not triggering on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I have a page that has an animation when the Iframe is loading. The page has a form on it for a user to a submit a url and the form's target is the iframe.

The loading animation works when the page loads the first time. but when the form is submitted, the animation does not work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but this is the code I have, if someone could help, thanks in advance.

```
<head>
<style>
#frameWrap {
    position:relative;
    height: 360px;
    width: 640px;
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #777777;
}

#iframe1 {
    height: 360px;
    width: 640px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}

#loader1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
    top:35%;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding:25px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    background:#ffffff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #777777;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form_container">
        <form id="tt1"  method="post" target="iframe1" action="convert.php">
            <input id="element_1" name="url1"  type="text"  value="http://"/> 
            <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />


       </form>  

<div id="frameWrap">
<img id="loader1" src="ajax_loader.gif" width="36" height="36" alt="loading gif"/>
<iframe id="iframe1" src="image.html" ></iframe>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
            $('#loader1').hide();
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form, the page "control" is transferred, so to speak, to the new URL - in your case, to convert.php. If the upload takes time, then the page will appear to sit there doing nothing. What you want is to use form.onSubmit and $('#loader1').show() in there, returning true.

```
// in ready()
$('#tt1').submit(function(){$('#loader1').show();return true;});
```

Comment: Am I suppose to put in the inline javascript I have like this?
`code`
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
             $('#loader1').hide();
         });
     });
  // in ready()
  $('#tt1').submit(function(){$('#loader1').show();return true;});
 </script>
`code`
If so I just tried that and it does not work. Sorry I am pretty novice at this point. But thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry you had it correct, I had the form ID named wrong mine.